# How to keep styled-components styles separate in different higher-order components on partially static site?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, next.js, styled-components, higher-order-components

I'm using higher order components to reuse React/Next.js components but with different styles. However, this works only for vanilla React where pages are not generated either server-side or statically. If some pages are static and others dynamic, it won't work.

Here's an example component. We'll focus on `TabStyles.Main` in a little while:

```
const Tabs: NextPage<Props> = ({ ... }: Props) => {
  ...
  return (
    <TabStyles.Main>
      ...
    </TabStyles.Main>
  );
};

export default Tabs;
```

Here're its styles:

```
import styled from "styled-components";

const Main = styled.div`
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
`;

...

export const TabStyles = {
  Main,
  ...
};
```

Now let's implement two HOCs.

In red.tsx, rendered at path /red, `color` is red:

```
// Import Tabs and TabStyles

const TabsFontRed = <P extends {}>(Component: NextPage<P>) => {
  TabStyles.Main = styled(TabStyles.Main)`
    color: red;
  `;

  const NewComp = (props: P) => <Component {...props} />;
  return NewComp;
};

const RedHOC = TabsFontRed(Tabs);
```

In blue.tsx, rendered at path /blue, `color` is blue.

```
// Import Tabs and TabStyles

const TabsFontBlue = <P extends {}>(Component: NextPage<P>) => {
  TabStyles.Main = styled(TabStyles.Main)`
    color: blue;
  `;

  const NewComp = (props: P) => <Component {...props} />;
  return NewComp;
};

const BlueHOC = TabsFontBlue(Tabs);
```

This works if all pages are dynamic because `TabStyles.Main = styled(TabStyles.Main)...` is called every time we load the page, thus changing `color` to the correct one.

However, it seems if /red is static but /blue isn't, as we might do with Next.js, the behaviour will be different:

- Go to /red first, font is red. Good.
- Go to /blue, font is blue. Also good.
- Go back to /red, font is now blue. Oh no!

Is there a way to augment this higher order component plus styled-components pattern so that styling will remain different when some pages are static and some are not?

### Edit, 1 April 2021:

React complains in the console if we do this. I lost the notice now but it makes me think this is a bad idea. Probably, overriding styles is not good use of higher order components. Now I think HOCs should be used for adding logic, not styles.

Override styled-components in conventional fashion like this:

```
const NewStyledComp = styled(OlderStyledComp)`
    background-color: ...;
`
```

Or like this:

```
const NewStyledComp = styled.div`
    ${OlderStyledComp} {
        background-color: ...;
    }
`
```

Comment: IMHO styled components defeat the purpose of CSS. It is not an approach I support at all. The presentation (CSS) should be separate from the content (HTML), and the functionality (JS). This is the way you can achieve most reusability: with proper separation of concerns.

Comment: @andriusain while I personally agree very much with your opinion, styled components are considered a valid design pattern when building modular applications, design systems etc.

Comment: @IngoSteinke I'm sure you're right. I still think that if you don't tightly couple the styles to the component you can reuse those styles in other components, which is more flexible. You would also not run into problems as the OP is having and things would not be over-engineered and would be easier to understand. Also I think CSS in JS has a performance hit versus being able to simply cache a CSS file. I'm still not sold on them, I do keep an open mind but remain to be convinced.